# Max / Argmax of a function which includes sums of Gaussian CDFs and PDFs can surprisingly be approximated by a power law

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions, gaussian

Given $N\in\mathbb{N}$, I have been trying to calculate $m_N=\text{max}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}}\chi_N(x), d_N=\text{argmax}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}}\chi_N(x)$ for the function:
$$\chi_N(x)=\frac{\sum_{i\in K_N}\sum_{j\in K_N}\phi(ix)\phi(jx)}{\sum_{i\in K_N}\sum_{j\in K_N}\Phi\left(-\max\left(i,j\right)x\right)\Phi\left(\min\left(i,j\right)x\right)}$$
Where $K_N=\left\{ k-\frac{N}{2}|\forall k\in\mathcal{\mathbb{N}},k<N\right\}$, and $\phi,\Phi$ are the gaussian PDF and CDF.

Solving those equations numerically over values of $N$ in the range $[3..1024]$, it appears that the following expressions, which I got using linear-regression over the numerical results, give a good approximation for the solution:

$m_N\simeq1-e^{0.71}(N+1)^{-1.81}$

$d_N\simeq e^{1.4}(N+1)^{-0.88}$

[Results of the numerical analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXrYf.png)

In fact- the numerical solution is accurate enough for me to suspect that there is some analytical solution/approximation that can better explain those relations. I calculated that for even $N$, $L\equiv\frac{N}{2}-1$, We get that $\frac{d\chi_N(x)}{dx}=0$ iff 
$$
\sum_{i=-L}^{L-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{L}\left[i\phi(ix)\Phi\left(-jx\right)+j\phi(jx)\Phi\left(ix\right)-x\left(i^{2}+j^{2}\right)\Phi\left(ix\right)\Phi\left(-jx\right)\right]+
$$
$$
\sum_{i=-L}^{L}\left(i\phi(ix)-xi^{2}\Phi\left(-ix\right)\right)\Phi\left(ix\right)=0
$$
but could not get further. I tried using approximations for the CDF and prove the $d_N$ law by induction, to no avail. Can this relation be better explained?
The method to to get to this equation is described in [this pdf (dropbox link)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc297hga3gu7gs5/mathoverflowQ.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: The numerator of $\chi$ is $\left(\sum_{i\in K_N}\phi(ix)\right)^2$; when $x$ is small and $N$ is large the sum in that expression is roughly a Riemann sum of the Gaussian distribution, so the numerator will be roughly $1/x^2$.